# How to choose RandomState in train_test_split?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I understand how random state is used to randomly split data into training and test set. As Expected, my algorithm gives different accuracy each time I change it. Now I have to submit a report in my university and I am unable to understand the final accuracy to mention there. Should I choose the maximum accuracy I get? Or should I run it with different RandomStates and then take its average? Or something else?

Comment: Didn't they specifiy a particular random state in the question or in the initial part of an answer?

Comment: Ultimately, you are building a model with the hope that it will have robust performance to new, unseen data. If you built a good model, then the accuracy should not vary too much depending on the random state. If you are seeing wild fluctuations, then your model is not good. Reporting the max accuracy would be bad, in my opinion, because it would not be representative of the real-world expected performance. My recommendation is to take the average over some number of runs or do k-fold CV, but report the standard deviation as well.

Comment: @MaxU Actually It is a minor project I chose on my own. It is a part of junior year curriculum at my university.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to take the average accuracy... but
you can take the best accuracy if you train the model based on that specific data set split to yield the best classification (may be considered as overfit) let me elaborate:

you can train the model for a few iteration the accuracy over the **test** and **train** set will vary but will take a up-ward trend (the accuracy will rise) 
you can train the model for a lot of iteration and update your weights only if the accuracy got better at this iteration, thus construct the best model...

**BUT** you should be careful to watch the accuracy of the **test set** to avoid overfitting i.e when the model can predict with very **high** accuracy over the **train** set but with very **low** accuracy over the **test** set

At start the model will learn and both (**test** and **train**) accuracy will improve, after a lot of training the **train accuracy will improve** (or stay the same) but the **test accuracy will drop**

you can take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) for further reading

I suggest you to take a look at [k-fold cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation), I think this method is best suited in this scenario

Comment: "but you can take the best accuracy if you train the model based on that specific data set split to yield the best classification (may be considered as overfit)". Please Elaborate.

Comment: @PrabhjeetSingh, added some explanation to the original answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, I set `random_state` to a specific number (usually `42`) so if I see variation in my programs accuracy I know it was **not** caused by how the data was split.

However, this can lead to my network over fitting on that specific split.  I.E. I tune my network so it works well with that split, but not necessarily on a different split.  Because of this, I think it's best to use a random seed when you submit your code so the reviewer knows you haven't over fit to that particular state.

To do this with `sklearn.train_test_split` you can simply not provide a `random_state` and it will pick one randomly using `np.random`.